# Update multiple records using dapper after select by uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, dapper

I have number of records that I have loaded from database and I want to update set couple values before I return them. The only main requirement I do not want multiple commands updating each record one by one.

Please note my ids are GUIDs(uniqueidentifier)

so far I have my code as

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetUnprocessedPeople(int batchSize)
    {
        List<Queue_ImportQueue> list;
        using (IDbConnection db = OpenedConnection)
        {
            string peopleList = $"SELECT TOP({batchSize}) * FROM [dbo].[Person]";

            list = db.Query<Person>(peopleList).ToList();
            using (IDbTransaction transactionScope = db.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
            {
                string updateQuery = $"UPDATE [dbo].[Person] SET Created = GETDATE() WHERE Id ='@ids'";

                try
                {
                    db.Execute(updateQuery, new { Id = list.Select(x => x.Id) }, transactionScope);
                    transactionScope.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transactionScope.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK the solution was quite simple.
There is no need for specific casting.
just ensure you have all arguments correct.
So extract that has fixed the query for me:

```
            string updateQuery = $"UPDATE [dbo].[Person] SET Created = GETDATE() WHERE Id ='@Ids'";

           ...

            db.Execute(updateQuery, new { Ids = list.Select(x => x.Id) }, transactionScope);
```

Comment: How can we update multiple columns with multipe contitions, if a have a list od data and multiple parameters in contines from list for example as below

Comment: How can we update multiple columns with multipe contitions, if i have a list of data and multiple parameters in condition from list for example $"UPDATE [dbo].[Person] SET Created = @date, IsActive=@Isactive  ''WHERE Id ='@Ids' and And PersonId='@PersonID'".... As i said i have a list of data containg 8 to 10 rows to be updated taking parameters from that list..how can we update

Comment: @KalpeshKoli it depends if you have same Id or multiple. The query above will execute for every id it has been given. In your case, you will have to create a list of parameters for each row. check the tutorial (https://dapper-tutorial.net/update) the list will be best suited for what you are describing.

Comment: large amount of paremeters( ids)  will  throw exceptions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15